# Github Copilot only has "Explain This" instead of start code that in trial of copilot X

Tags: github-copilot

anyone else here who cant use the "start code that" from the copilot pre release? I reinstalled the extensions but it didnt work for me. Do you have the same issue?

Cheers

[image: Only "Explain This"]